# Update using stored procedure in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server which will update the table if records exists else it will insert records into the table

Here's the code for the stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_update]
    (@sender VARCHAR(50),
     @receiver VARCHAR(50),
     @no INT,
     @mas INT,
     @sha INT,
     @not INT,
     @ever INT,
     @love INT,
     @tele INT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM links
               WHERE sender = @sender
                 AND receiver = @receiver
                 AND no = @no
                 AND mas = @mas
                 AND sha = @sha 
                 AND not = @not
                 AND ever = @ever
                 AND love = @love
                 AND tele = @tele)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE links 
        SET sender = ISNULL(@sender, sender),
            receiver = ISNULL(@receiver, receiver), 
            no = ISNULL(@no, no),
            mas = ISNULL(@mas, mas),
            sha = ISNULL(@sha, sha), 
            not = ISNULL(@not, not),
            ever = ISNULL(@ever, ever),
            love = ISNULL(@love, love),
            tele = ISNULL(@tele, tele) 
        WHERE 
            sender = @sender 
            AND receiver = @receiver
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO links 
        VALUES (@sender, @receiver, @no, @mas, @sha, @not, @ever, @love, @tele)
    END
END
```

Now I want to update only few columns if records already exists, so here is the code behind:

```
sql.Open();

SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("insert_update", sql);
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sender",  Request.QueryString["sender"]);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receiver", Request.QueryString["reciever"]);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no",  Request.QueryString["one".ToString()]);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mas", Request.QueryString["two".ToString()]);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sha", Request.QueryString["three".ToString()]);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@not", Request.QueryString["four".ToString()]);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ever", Request.QueryString["five".ToString()]);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@love", Request.QueryString["six".ToString()]);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tele", Request.QueryString["seven".ToString()]);

Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sql.Close();
```

Whenever I try to update, I get an error

> Procedure or function 'insert_update' expects parameter '@mas', which was not supplied.

So how to update only a few columns?

Comment: Why are you passing strings to a int column?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Your parameters of type `VARCHAR` will in fact be **exactly ONE character** long - no more. Any string you pass in is silently truncated - typically *not* what you want! Fix this ASAP

Comment: **Typo alert**: the verb is **to receive**, and the noun is **receiver** (not "reciever" as you misspelled it several times)

Comment: I'd suggest that having a column called `not` is going to catch you out at some point. Also, SqlCommand is IDisposable so should be in a `using` block. And you may want to take a look at [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `stored procedure` definition so that procedure should not expect values for each parameter. We can specify default values for each parameter in `stored procedure` definition as shown below -

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_update]
(
    @sender varchar=null,
    @reciever varchar=null,
    @no int=null,
    @mas int=null,
    @sha int=null,
    @not int=null,
    @ever int=null,
    @love int=null,
    @tele int=null
)......
```

Comment: wow! it worked. But, instead of updating, a new row is getting added. i want to update records such that the new value gets added to the previous record in the column. for example i want to do this-                                                                            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", no+ Request.QueryString["one".ToString()]);

Comment: Have a look at your IF EXISTS check - your WHERE clause is checking far too much. It looks like it should only be checking sender and reciever which I assume is what identifies a row